# How to count and get child items of the last level of tree view node in vb net?

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I want to count and get child name of treeview if there is only on root element like the following picture. I am in Item1 position.

```
 Item1
    |_____SubItem1
                 |___A
                 |___B
```

The result should be `Count:2`, Item: `A, B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also a possible solution, using LINQ:

```
Dim result = (From node as TreeNode in TreeView1.TopNode.Nodes
              Select New With {
                .Count = node.Nodes.Count,
                .Items = String.Join(",", node.Nodes.Cast(Of TreeNode).AsEnumerable().Select(Function(childNode) childNode.Name).ToArray())
              })
```

Comment: @scroeder Thank. Your solution is short and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This solution relies on your TreeView depth not changing. If you're going to have deeper levels, you'll need to smarten it up.

```
       For Each nd As TreeNode In TestTreeView.Nodes
            If nd.Nodes.Count > 0 Then 'it has children, lets look at them
                For Each ndChild As TreeNode In nd.Nodes
                    If ndChild.Nodes.Count > 0 Then 'it has children, lets look at them
                        Dim outputText As String = String.Concat(ndChild.Text, " ",
                                                                 ndChild.Nodes.Count)
                        For Each ndSubChild As TreeNode In ndChild.Nodes
                            outputText = String.Concat(outputText, " ", ndSubChild.Text)
                        Next
                        Debug.Print(outputText)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I haven't reply long time, so sorry. This solution is to list all items in each node. I get some idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
**'Its work for me. Thanks** 




 Dim outputText As String


        For Each nd As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes
            If nd.Nodes.Count > 0 Then 'it has children, lets look at them
                For Each ndChild As TreeNode In nd.Nodes
                    outputText = String.Concat(ndChild.Text, " - (Total : ", ndChild.Nodes.Count, ")")
                    TextBox4.Text += outputText & vbNewLine

                    If ndChild.Nodes.Count > 0 Then 'it has children, lets look at them
                        For Each ndSubChild As TreeNode In ndChild.Nodes
                            outputText = String.Concat(vbTab, " - ", ndSubChild.Text)
                            TextBox4.Text += outputText & vbNewLine

                            If ndSubChild.Nodes.Count > 0 Then 'it has children, lets look at them
                                For Each ndSubSubChild As TreeNode In ndSubChild.Nodes
                                    outputText = String.Concat(vbTab, vbTab, " - ", ndSubSubChild.Text)
                                    TextBox4.Text += outputText & vbNewLine
                                Next
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
```